# Im having trouble logging JSON data to the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

my api link works fine when i copy and paste it into a tab, but my jquery code to get the JSON data and log it into the console does not work. replacing http with https doesn't work either.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
q=London&APPID=<myAppId>"
$.getJSON(api, function(data){
console.log(data.weather.main);

});
});
```

Comment: So do you get an error? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: Define "does not work."  Error message? No response? Unexpected data?

Comment: `data.weather[0].main` should work

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after your `var api = ""`

Comment: I get no response from the console.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` show you all

Comment: still no response...

Answer (score 0):

Try the $.ajax instead to get the error message, in the following way:

```
    var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID=<myAppId>"
    $.ajax({
        url: api,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log("success", data);
    })
    .fail(function(a,b,c) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(a+b+c);
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
```

The .fail function will bring you back the error message, in case it's server sided.